# How to use getIntent.getExtra() in tab fragment

Tags: android, tabs

currently i doing an android app which need to connect and use tab to show different categories of product. In activity, i able to run the code below to get extra but cannot run in tab fragment. In tab fragment, the function class for showDialogBox,getExtra and isNetworkConnected() cannot run. I use the AppBarLayout example that show in http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator/ and some addition code. Tq.

```
try { getExtra(savedInstanceState);
        if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
            if(language == 0)
                showDialogBox("Dashboard","No internet connection, please turn on your network connection");
            else if(language == 1)
                showDialogBox("主页","无法上网, 请打开网路.");
            else
                showDialogBox("Papan Pemuka","Tiada internet, sila buka sambungan internet anda");
            this.finish();
            return;
        }
        //some code here
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                   //some code here
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }).start();

    } catch (Exception ex) {}

private void showDialogBox(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle(title);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        // @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private void getExtra(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // get params frm previous page/////
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            custID = extras.getString("CUSID");
        }
    }
}
 private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Network Connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the get the Activity from a fragment via `getActivity()`. So do `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()`

Comment: In this line `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
`change to `Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(); ` Is your error Cannot resolve getIntent()? Can you post your entire class?

Comment: u mean put in fragment or activity?

Comment: Are you calling it in the fragment? Then yes.